# ReactNativeJS: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.default')

Tags: android, react-native, typeerror, release

App is running properly without any error in debug mode.but its crashing in release mode after splash screen. and also when i'm trying to archive it,its getting successful archive but im not getting anything under window.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
"mobx": "^5.15.4",
"mobx-react": "^6.2.2",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-device-info": "^5.5.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
"react-native-image-gallery": "^2.1.4",
"react-native-image-view": "^2.1.2",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.7.3",
"react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"react-native-share": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-slideshow": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
"react-native-svg": "^12.0.3",
"react-native-unity-ads": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
"eslint": "^6.5.1",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has this issue resolved for you?